# Cannot Create Role

Tags: magento-1.9

When i try to create a new role i get the following error message :

> Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Slidermanger_Helper_Data' not found in
>   /var/www/html/app/Mage.php on line 547

Find block of code that has 547 as its last line:

```
$registryKey = '_helper/' . $name;
if (!self::registry($registryKey)) {
    $helperClass = self::getConfig()->getHelperClassName($name);
    self::register($registryKey, new $helperClass);
```

Comment: please provide `Slidermanger` extension adminhtml.xml and config.xml file I have solve this error in past

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara You should read the question before stating that this is a possible duplicate of another question. This is nothing like that question. The title of this question could be better but it is definitely NOT a duplicate.

Comment: @ShawnAbramson, i retracted that flag on this.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this issue before as well. You need to see if that class actually exists. It would either be located at

`app/code/local/{vendorname}/Slidermanager/Helper/Data.php`
OR
`app/code/community/{vendorname}/Slidermanager/Helper/Data.php`

If it does not exist in that location, that means the module's create was supposed to create but forgot to. You can create and install an empty one and your error will go away. Here is what you should create:

```
<?php

class {Vendorname}_Slidermanager_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibility 1;

This issue might be happen if you have disable your slidermanger extension and its helper class in use just like `$this->helper('slidermanger')`

Possibility 2;

your helper config defination not match your module in your `config.xml` or `adminhtml.xml`

for example defination of helper

```
<helpers>
        <slidermanager>
            <class>YourVendor_Slidermanager_Helper</class>
        </slidermanager>
</helpers>
```

and use of helper

```
<slidermanager module="slidermanager">
```

Here module name should match with helper node of config.xml